# Calling print() on a frame in javascript hangs IE 8 browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I want to print a particular frame in an array indexed by name. I am using the following code:

```
var frame_name = "abc"; 
frames_array[frame_name].focus(); 
frames_array[frame_name].print();
```

When it executes print() statement in IE8, it hangs. This piece of code works correctly in Firefox, Chrome and IE9.

I tried `frames_array[frame_name].document.close()` but it did not change anything. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: Ah. Why would someone be copying and pasting the vote counter when asking a question? Anyway, so it was a failure to proofread, rather than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this function.It will work.

```
function printDiv() {
 var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printArea');
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.innerHTML)
    newWin.document.close();
    newWin.focus();
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();

}
```

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

even this did not worked. I guess the problem is that I am not opening a new window for printing but directly print the frame on which button is present.

Comment: This worked for me, except that if you use an iframe, you need to remove the `newWin.close();` line.

Answer (score 0):

even this did not worked. I guess the problem is that I am not opening a new window for printing but directly print the frame on which button is present.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

even this did not worked. I guess the problem is that I am not opening a new window for printing but directly print the frame on which button is present.

Answer (score -1):

Try `frames_array[frame_name].document.execCommand('print', false, null);`